# AngularJS bind model to ngRepeat (and evalute it)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a basic crud app, and i hide columns in a table to show just the input the user wants to see. I managed to show/hide the input by binding a `ng-model` to a table column and the same model to a checkbox, so it hides when the checkbox is checked.

Because i have a lot of data i don't want to keep the inputs in my template, so i decided to `ng-repeat` them instead.

Heres my controller:

```
// simplified for this Q
$scope.columns = [
    { name: '#ID', checked: false, model: 'checkedId' },
    { name: 'Container', checked: false, model: 'checkedContainer' },
    { name: 'Type', checked: true, model: 'checkedType' }
];
```

This is in my html (before it is rendered):

```
<label ng-repeat="col in columns">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cols[]" value="{{col.name}}"
        ng-checked="col.checked" ng-model="col.model"><span>{{col.name}}</span>
</label>
```

The rendered html looks like this: (for the second item in the array [array slot 1])

```
<label ng-repeat="col in columns" class="ng-scope">
    <input type="checkbox" name="cols[]" value="Container" 
        ng-checked="col.checked"
        ng-model="col.model" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <span class="ng-binding">Container</span>
</label>
```

I hide the elements like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkedContainer"><span>checkedId</span>
```

The element that is to be hidden looks like this (another repeater)

```
<td class="check-element" ng-hide="checkedContainer">{{ c.container }}</td>
```

So the mg-model is bound the column, and if i manually insert the input like above, it works. But when looping it doesnt. I recon the problem is with the loop. So that the model is not evaluted, but stays as "col-model" in the html. Is there a way to evalute the model to the corresponding model in the `$scope.columns` array?

Basically i would want my `$scope.columns.model`to be evaluted to the model it belongs to. I managed to get the values bound with changing mg-model to ng-bind, but that doesnt work for the data-binding, as i understand its only one-way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround, add `$scope.scope = $scope;` in your scope and then assign model like:

```
ng-model="scope[col.model]"
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/Ydbhj/

UPDATE: Got it! As we know , `ng-repeat` creates a new `scope` , so this will work in this case:

```
ng-model="$parent[col.model]"
```

And no need in `$scope.scope = $scope;`

Final solution: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/4CTgr/